# Android Dynamic Screen layout : Content should be retireved from database

Tags: android, layout, dynamic

I am trying for dynamic screen layout like it is in ladoo app, 
I am listing few jobs for the app users to complete tasks and What I need is, If user complete one task from listing that job should be vanished from the list.
Can someone guide me in loading dynamic screens in my app. Thanks

Comment: i am not sure of ladoo app but u can use cursor loader

Comment: Dynamic screens ? what it meant to be, you can use fragments.